# Is there a way to have weak binding in KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

I have a dialog which is used to create 2 sets of data which are switched using a radio button at the top.  Depending on the selected value, some fields are removed from the UI (i.e. Admin User and Normal Users).

However, when I try and bind the form to the original serialised data, some items don't exist so I get binding errors.  However, I expect this, as the dialog will have some fields hidden and I don't want some fields to bind just by way of the data not being in the serialised model.  Is there a way to ensure that rather than throwing a binding error, the data item simply silently fails?

I'm using KnockoutJS 1.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably use the `if` binding which essentially does what you want. It simply doesn't render what's within the if binding.

Here are the docs: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html

Comment: I just had a look at the 1.2.1 source at github and seems that it doesn't. You will have no problem updating to 2.0 though. I can't remember any breaking changes in my code anyway.

Comment: I've upgraded but I have following problem: <td style="background-color: rgba( ${ HeatColorValue.R }, ${ HeatColorValue.G }, ${ HeatColorValue.B }, 0.7 )">. How do I convert to native template?

Comment: @jaffa: sounds like you want something like <!-- ko if: HeatColorValue --> then your code, then <!-- /ko -->. Now if HeatColorValue is null, it won't render your code.